# Matplotlib showing points only - not line

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

My matplotlib graph is not showing a solid line. It only shows the actual points. I even specify the line width. Can't figure out why it's not showing up.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

graphArray = []
MyData = open("SampleText.txt","r").read()
Split_by_line = MyData.split('\n')

for item in Split_by_line:
    splitInfo = item.split(',')

    graphArrayAppend = splitInfo[0]+','+splitInfo[1]
    graphArray.append(graphArrayAppend)
datestamp, value= np.loadtxt(graphArray,delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                             converters={ 0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

ax.plot_date(x=datestamp, y=value, linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

SampleText.csv

```
2014-01-01,6
2014-01-02,9
2014-01-03,4
2014-01-04,7
2014-01-05,7
2014-01-06,4
2014-01-07,4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of the `fmt` (format) argument to plot date is `'o'`, for drawing points. Replace it with `-` to draw a line:

```
ax.plot_date(x=datestamp, y=value, fmt='-', linewidth=2)
```